# Can I set the color/format with the &-Operator in Excel?

Tags: excel, colors, format

I have an Excel-document which looks like this

```
A       B        
apple   banana   
banana  fig
```

and I want this as a result.

```
A       B        C 
apple   banana   applebanana
banana  fig      bananafig
```

BUT I want Excel to **keep the original colors**.

Using C1=A1&B1 I could achieve this [image]

Using the fruits-example:
The result is for "applebanana" written in standard format.
But I want the C column to keep the colors of A and B:

The word "apple" is always red and "banana" is always written in yellow. And my desired result in C1 would be "applebanana" BUT with the letters of "apple" in red and the "banana"-part in yellow.

Is this possible with Excel? I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: No. Formulas can't apply formatting, and any cell with a formula in can only have formats applied to the whole cell, not individual words.

Comment: You need a VBA solution for this.  Excel can only differentially format parts of a string if that string is just a string, and not the result of a formula.